# Oldest Department of the Company SQL Query

Tags: sql

Sample human_resource.csv dataset.

| id | department | hire_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00-0037846 | Engineering | 2002-01-20 |
| 00-0041533 | Business Development | 2019-04-08 |
| 00-0045747 | Sales | 2010-10-12 |
| 00-0055274 | Services | 2005-04-10 |

Original dataset: [Human Resources.csv](https://data.world/markbradbourne/rwfd-real-world-fake-data/workspace/file?filename=Human%20Resources.csv)

What is the oldest department of the company? Think like .. the early an employee joins, the older the department is.

I am trying to write query using SQL.

Firstly I find out the logic to solve this question and here is the logic.

**Logic**: do a row-wise subtraction of current date - hiring date of each employee and then encapsulate it in max and also add `Group by` department. Don't forget to sort result to get oldest.

So this is the SQL query I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    department, 
    MAX(YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(hire_date)) OldestDept 
FROM 
    human_resources 
GROUP BY 
    department 
ORDER BY 
    OldestDept DESC;
```

Output:

[image]

I think something is wrong in the query. Please advice and sorry for my bad English. Thanks

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you're looking for.

```
SELECT department
FROM human_resources WHERE hire_date = (SELECT MIN(hire_date) FROM human_resources)
```